# User permission on SharePoint 2013 design package

Tags: permissions, css, branding

I have created my own bespoke design package for SP2013 and imported without issues and it all looks great to me as the admin logged in.  I have invited other users into my dev site and when they login it looks like the CSS is not loading for those users.

I'm guessing this is a permissions issue but cannot for the life of me work out how to fix this...anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you need to track down the files used in your design package and select them all individually and "publish a major version" to get them all to be available to users other than admin (or the person who imported the design package)